# Why CRC value of a binary geneated on Cygwin and Linux environment are different

Tags: makefile, cygwin, crc

I have a Makefile which generate  binary, the problem is CRC values of same binary which is generated on Cygwin and Linux environment are different. what would be the reason.

Environment: Cygwin 64 bit
Linux 64 bit

Comment: It would be truly bizarre if it _didn't_ change.

Comment: @MarkAdler if this question is about cross-compilation as I assume, then the same toolchain version could or rather should indeed produce the identical CRC, sans incorproration of timestamps or user credentials

Comment: I see nothing that would suggest this is about cross-compilation.

Answer (score 2):

The CRC changes because the executable file's contents changed. There is many reasons why the contents might change, but the main reason for you is that windows uses the `PE32+` (or `PE32` if you are using 32 bit machine) format and linux uses `ELF` format (macos uses `March-O`). Their headers and stuff are different so their CRC will be different.

Sometimes binary built on 2 different machines with the same OS will be different too. The reason is that the library path is different, or a machine got clang 12 and another got clang 15.

Also the generated file is not a C binary, it is a executable. A binary is just machine code (and a bit of data for the const values), with no other information, so the OS will have no way to run it (it doesn't know the libs to dynamic link to, the entry position...).

Comment: thanks for the your valueable information. i have both Linu and Cygwin with 64 bit, can we fix this CRC content by comparing the content of binary or we can't fix this issue at all in any way.
 
Could you please briefe this point  "windows uses the PE32+ (or PE32 if you are using 32 bit machine) format and linux uses ELF"

Comment: Run either of these commands `xxd /bin/ls | head`  or `hexdump -C /bin/ls | head` on both linux and cygwin.

Comment: There is no way to fix this if you want a exe for windows and a exe for linux, since linux can't run PE32+ and windows can't run ELF. Why this happened? Mostly because Microsoft is bad. Everyone other OS uses ELF, but Microsoft just uses PE32+